# In NetBeans, how do I remove this red underline?

Tags: netbeans

I've added the following comment to the start of a Java program:

```
/**   
 *  
 * George Tomlinson (I'm not the author).  I took this from the *internet* and made one correction.  
 * This program converts the string entered by the user from hexadecimal to ASCII.   
 */
```

The word 'internet' (italicised above but *not* in the actual program) is being underlined in red by NetBeans. The error it displays is 'misspelled word', but it's not misspelled. In Word I would just add it to the dictionary, but I can't find any such option here. Does anyone know how to sort this out?

You can see a screenshot here:

[image: Screenshot with red underline]

Comment: Try Internet with a capital I ;) Or place the cursor somewhere in the word and hit Alt+Enter.

Comment: Why don't you put that as an answer which I can accept?  They like to have questions answered as quickly as possible I think. Otherwise an answered question is going to be under the unanswered questions.  Not life or death maybe, but if something's worth doing, it's worth doing well. Otherwise, I'll put the answer up myself, but it will take 24hrs before I can accept it. @Maciej Stachowski

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Put the cursor on the word
2. Press Alt + Enter

Comment: And another question that arises for anyone bothered about spelling: is the author of this feature in NetBeans correct in saying that internet should be Internet?

Comment: Amusingly, there's a whole webpage on the subject, which is apparently a matter of convention: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization_of_%22Internet%22

Answer (score 86):

Try

**For remove vertical red line:**

```
Tools : Options : Editor : Formatting ,

set Right Margin: 0
```

**For spelling check:**

```
Tools : Options : Editor : Spellchecker ,

you can add new spelling & other things.
```

may this help you.

Comment: Note: You must select "All Languages" in the "Language" menu of the "Formatting" tab.

Answer (score 8):

Follow the instruction to remove the red line which is just margin. It is called right margin. Go to menu

```
Tools ->Options -> Editor -> Formatting
```

set

```
right  margin = 0
```

Answer (score 7):

You can adjust the placement of the red line in (Netbeans 6.7): 
`Tools > Options > Editor > Formatting`.

On the left you'll see Right Margin, with a default value of 80.

If you want to remove the red line all together, you can either:

1. Increase the margin value to 160 or more; or goto
2. Tools > Options > Fonts and Colors, change the color of the Text Limit Line to white

Comment: Tools > Options > Fonts and Colors -> Highlighting (NB 8)

Answer (score 4):

Go to

```
Tools | Options | Editor | Spellchecker
```

and there you can turn spellchecker off (for particular types of text / text files) or upload one with 'internet' word according to your taste. Keep in mind that it is an IDE and not an text processor.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Preferences > Editor > Formatting 
Then untick "Use All Language Settings"
Set Right Margin: 0

Answer (score 2):

In osx Sierra and Netbeans 8.2 I had some difficulties to find where to set `Right Margin`

After you open `Preferences -> Editor -> Formatting` by default I had `Java` selected in `Language` drop down and `Right Margin` is greyed out.

Select `All Languages` and then set `Right margin`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is set according to the coding standard of maximum 80 characters per line. You can increase that from Tools->Options. Editor. Right margin. If you do not want to see it, just set  value greater than your screen size ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Tools - Options - Editor - Formatting - Right Margin [0 or more of 80]

[image: red line netbeans]

Answer (score 0):

set right margin to 0 rather then 160 or more